# when i try to get the unicode of emoji, why i got some unicode like de01, de02, de03?

Tags: android, unicode, emoji

[img description: first one was textview to get unicode; second one was textview to restore emoji; last one was edittext to input text or emoji](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqSRZ.jpg)

and post my code below

```
String s = emojiconEditText.getText().toString();
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder stringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
 private void testTwo(String s, StringBuilder stringBuilder, StringBuilder stringBuilder1, TextView emojiconText, TextView emojiconText2) {
        int codePointCount = s.codePointCount(0, s.length() - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i <codePointCount ; i++) {
            int letterCodePoint = s.codePointAt(i);
            int type = Character.getType(letterCodePoint);
            if (type==Character.SURROGATE||type==Character.OTHER_SYMBOL){
                stringBuilder.append("[emoji]U+"+Integer.toHexString(letterCodePoint)+"[emoji]");
            }else{
                stringBuilder.append(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        String text = stringBuilder.toString();
        emojiconText.setText(text);

        String[] emojis = text.split("\\[emoji\\]");
        for (int i = 0; i <emojis.length ; i++) {
            if (emojis[i].contains("U+")){
           //     String[] subSplit = emojis[i].split("[/emoji]");
         //       int deccode = Integer.parseInt(subSplit[0], 16);
                String substring = emojis[i].substring(2, emojis[i].length() );
                int deccode = Integer.parseInt(
                        substring, 16);
               /* stringBuilder1.append("\\u");
                stringBuilder1.append( deccode);*/
                stringBuilder1.append(new String(Character.toChars(deccode))+" ");

            }else{
                stringBuilder1.append(emojis[i]);
            }
        }
        emojiconText2.setText(stringBuilder1.toString());
    }
```

Comment: You are mixing the concepts of Java `char` and unicode code points. `s.codePointAt(i)` gives you the code point starting at char position `i`, not the `i`-th code point.

Comment: Thanks very much! Your reply really help me a lot. I have fixed this bug